# Установить в input current->name а в value current->id

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть выпадающий список в котором сейчас при выборе элемента устанавливается его Имя + в value тоже идет Имя. Мне необходимо чтобы при выборе в выпадающем списке у меня устанавливалось Имя а в value Id имени

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выпадающий список

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control js-input" name="address" value="">
    <ul class="box-form-list">
        @foreach ($regions as $current)

           <li class="box-form-list__item">
                                            
                <a href="#" class="js-link">{{ $current->name }}</a>
            </li>

        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

jquery

```js
$('.js-input').keyup(function(){

    if($(this).val() != '') {
        $('.box-form-list').slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('.box-form-list').slideUp();
    }
});

$('.js-link').click(function () {
    let LinkText = $(this).text();

    $('.js-input').val(LinkText).attr('value', LinkText);
    $('.box-form-list').slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделай @foreach:

```
@foreach ($regions as $current)    
    <li class="box-form-list__item">                                                
        <a href="#" class="js-link" data-currentId="{{ $current->id }}">{{ $current->name }}</a>
    </li>    
@endforeach
```

поправь если по php что то не верно.

И в js добавь:

```
$('.js-link').click(function () {
    let LinkText = $(this).text();
    let currentId = $(this).data().currentId;

    $('.js-input').val(LinkText).attr('value', currentId);
    $('.box-form-list').slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: почему-то не может обратиться к данному элементу http://i.imgur.com/E5B1pvc.png

js
http://i.imgur.com/vtMOkJi.png

html
http://i.imgur.com/zecHYtd.png

Comment: немного поправил js http://i.imgur.com/L2aZMBT.png
сейчас все ок спасибо вам!

Comment: принял ответ как правильный